# Fatal error editing core data objects

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I am newbie to programming. With CoreData, I am trying to create the function to edit the data in input text field to edit the data to be saved to core data. I am having `fatal error`:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Coursework")

        do {

            let results = try manageContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

            let attribute = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            detailItem?.value = modulename.text

            attribute.setValue(courseworkname.text, forkey: "courseworkname")
            attribute.setValue(dueDateLabel.text, forkey: "duedate")
            attribute.setValue(level.text, forkey: "level")
            attribute.setValue(mark.text, forkey: "mark")
            attribute.setValue(modulename.text, forkey: "modulename")
            attribute.setValue(notes.text, forkey: "notes")
            attribute.setValue(progressbar.text, forkey: "progressbar")
            attribute.setValue(reminder.text, forkey: "reminder")
            attribute.setValue(value.text, forkey: "value")

            try manageContext.save()

            }catch let error as NSError {
        }
}
```

---

Full code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dueDateLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var value: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseworkname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var modulename: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var level: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mark: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var reminder: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notes: UITextField!

    @IBAction func edit(sender: AnyObject) {

        modulename.userInteractionEnabled = true
        modulename.enabled = true 
        dueDateLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        value.userInteractionEnabled = true
        modulename.userInteractionEnabled = true
        level.userInteractionEnabled = true
        mark.userInteractionEnabled = true
        reminder.userInteractionEnabled = true
        notes.userInteractionEnabled = true

        //Interaction

        value.enabled = true
        dueDateLabel.enabled = true
        courseworkname.enabled = true
        modulename.enabled = true
        level.enabled = true
        mark.enabled = true
        reminder.enabled = true
        notes.enabled = true

    }

    @IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Coursework")

        do {

            let results = try manageContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)


            let attribute = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            detailItem?.value = modulename.text

            attribute.setValue(courseworkname.text, forKey: "courseworkname")
       attribute.setValue(dueDateLabel.text, forKey: "duedate")
            attribute.setValue(level.text, forKey: "level")
              attribute.setValue(mark.text, forKey: "mark")
              attribute.setValue(modulename.text, forKey: "modulename")
            attribute.setValue(notes.text, forKey: "notes")
             attribute.setValue(progressbar.text, forKey: "progressbar")
                attribute.setValue(reminder.text, forKey: "reminder")
        attribute.setValue(value.text, forKey: "value")



         try manageContext.save()

        }catch let error as NSError{     

        }

    }

    var detailItem: Coursework?
         var detailItem2: Task?

            {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.courseworkname
            }
            if let label = self.dueDateLabel {
                label.text = detail.duedate
            }

            if let label = self.value {
                label.text = detail.value
            }

            if let label = self.courseworkname {
                label.text = detail.courseworkname
            }

            if let label = self.modulename {
                label.text = detail.modulename
            }

            if let label = self.level {
                label.text = detail.level
            }

            if let label = self.mark {
                label.text = detail.mark
            }

            if let label = self.reminder{
                label.text = detail.reminder
            }

            if let label = self.notes{
                label.text = detail.notes

            }

        }
```

Comment: In which line does this error happens?

Comment: Can you show your variables and/or IBOutlets which you're using to get these values?

Comment: Added the full code. Happens on the line attribute.setValue(progressbar.text, forKey: "progress bar") -bad executtion

Answer (score 0):

Is it a new attribute?  You have to uninstall and reinstall the app when you're changing your CoreData models.

Also just saw that you don't have an IBOutlet defined for progressbar, if you link it it should work.

Comment: please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift you content quality up